# Топливо: есть ли множественное число?

Tags: существительные, единственное-множественное-число

Я бы сказал:

> различные виды топлива

но факты - упрямая вещь и в литературе увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: [Газификация конденсированных топлив: ретроспективный обзор, современное...](https://books.google.ru/books?id=V8-mBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%22&source=bl&ots=KPyxYe-pAX&sig=f2e4TnOMSaP4OCfc8Wxfvuz39sU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigi5j_4avLAhUkLZoKHfdKAK0Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%22&f=false)

Рассудите, кто прав.

Comment: В профессиональной речи еще и не то услышишь. Например, в сберкассе говорили исключительно "дневник" с ударением на Е. А рОзлив пива?! Это не значит, что в своей речи нужно употреблять их...

Comment: А рОзлив пива какое отношение к мн. числу имеет?

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере форма мн.ч. абсолютна корректна: здесь форма мн.ч. обозначает не количество топлива, а виды, сорта топлива.

Вещественные существенные существительные могут иметь форму множественного числа, которая обозначает не множество предметов, а сорта или сплошную массу веществ: (смазочные) масла, (минеральные) воды, (лечебные) грязи, (белые и красные) глины и т. д.

См.: [Основа культуры русской речи, стр.6](http://moy-bereg.ru/kultura-russkoy-rechi/osnova-kulturyi-russkoy-rechi.html)

Comment: Но ведь после посещения шоколадной фабрики вы вряд ли скажете: "Мы пробовали разные **шоколады*", а скорее - "различные сорта шоколада". Как это объяснить?

Comment: Важным условием здесь является изменение значения. Ср.: вода — воды океана, газированные воды; песок — пески Каракумов;масла (машинное, подсолнечное, сливочное, рапсовое, оливковое)бумага «материал для письма, печати» – бумаги «документы официального характера»).

Answer (score 1):

Есть правило употребления имен существительных с *вещественным* значением в форме множественного числа для обозначения различных сортов или видов вещества: *глины, масла, цементы* и др. (см. справочник по русскому языку, авторы Розенталь, Джанджакова, Кабанова).

Но не все вещественные существительные подчиняются этому правилу. Установить это можно по толковому словарю (Ожегова, например). *Топливо* не имеет множественного числа, а *масло* имеет с пометкой его *сорта.*

В профессиональной речи сейчас *допускается* употребление формы множественного числа.

Comment: Топливо имеет мн.ч. Можете прочитать по ссылке.

Comment: Покажите это в словаре, и без вопросов соглашусь.

Comment: Наберите в словарях на академике "топлива" убедитесь. Дизельные топлива, Реактивные топлива), котельные топлива и др. Топлива с высоким содержанием водорода. См.: Химическая энциклопедия.  Справочник технического переводчика. Словарь-справочник терминов нормативно-технической документации.

Comment: Слово "Топливо" во множественном числе? 

***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Форма мн. ч. вещественных существительных (_топлива_) допустима   в профессиональной речи.

Comment: Этого достаточно?

Comment: Отредактировано

Comment: Все равно *допускается* не значит *рекомендуется* (похоже на уступку тому, что уже существует ). Язык меняется.

Comment: Допускается в языке профессионалов., Это значит, что такая форма свойственна профессиональной речи, а повседневной.  Об этом свидетельствуют примеры. О рекомендации там ничего  не говорилось.